# Raspagem de dados com jsoup e salvando em txt

Tags: java, web-scraping, scraping

Opa, como vai galera. 
Estou tentando aprender raspagem de dados por conta, e como meu ingles não ajuda, estou me virando nos 30. Basicamente é o seguinte. Ao executar meu codigo, ele lista os atletas da Federação internacional de judo, um embaixo do outro. Eu descobri que cada iteração, ele pega todos de um pais de uma uma vez. Então a String vira um bloco com todos os atletas desse pais. Eu gostaria de fazer separação para pegar um atleta por vez, mas não consegui.  Então, ao imprimir, ele imprime um embaixo do outro, porém, ao mandar para o txt, ele não faz isso, ele coloca tudo na mesma linha e só pula quando muda de pais. Outra coisa que percebi é que ele cola o ultimo nome de um atleta ao primeiro do próximo.
 Exemplo: O codigo esta salvando dessa forma o txt:

> 0_  Afghanistan ABDUL HADI Gada KhilAFGHAN ZergulAHMADI Ahmad
>   ShabirALIPOOR Abdul HadiARMAN KhaledARYAN Mod ReshadASSADI YahyaASSADI
>   RohullahBAKHSHI Mohammad tawfiqBAREKZAI Ahmad HamedBAYAT HabibaFAIZ
>   ZADA AjmalFAIZZADA Ajmal FAZLI Abdul FahimHUSSAINI AtefaHUSSAINI Sayed
>   Hussain

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

> 0_  Afghanistan
>
> ABDUL HADI Gada Khil
>
> AFGHAN Zergul
>
> AHMADI Ahmad Shabir
>
> ALIPOOR Abdul Hadi
>
> ARMAN Khaled
>
> ARYAN Mod Reshad
>
> ASSADI Yahya
>
> ASSADI Rohullah
>
> BAKHSHI Mohammad tawfiq
>
> BAREKZAI Ahmad Hamed
>
> BAYAT Habiba

Segue meu código.

```
package pack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // Nesse bloco eu estou pegando os paises e suas siglas e inserindo no bd para usar na url de raspagem de atletas.
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ijf.org/judoka?name=&nation=all&gender=both&category=all").get();
        String paises = doc.select("option").text().replace(")", ")\n").replaceAll("All","").toString();
        int pos = paises.indexOf(")")+1;
        int quebra = paises.indexOf("\n")+1;
        int i=0;    

        ArrayList<Nacoes>bd = new ArrayList<>();
        String pais = "a", sigla ;
        while (pais.length()>0) {
            Nacoes n = new Nacoes();
            pais = paises.substring(0,pos);
            sigla = pais.substring(pais.length()-4, pais.length()-1);
            pais = pais.substring(0,pais.length()-5);            
            paises = paises.substring(quebra,paises.length());
            quebra = paises.indexOf("\n")+1;
            pos = paises.indexOf(")")+1;
            n.setPais(pais);
            n.setSigla(sigla);
            bd.add(n);      
            i++;
            pais = paises.substring(0,pos);
        }


        File arquivo = new File("C:\\ifjAtletas.txt");   
        FileWriter grava = new FileWriter(arquivo);
        PrintWriter escreve = new PrintWriter(grava);

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc2 = null;
        String inHtml = ("https://www.ijf.org/judoka?name=&nation=");
        String fimHtml = ("&gender=both&category=all");
        i=0;

        while(i<5) {
            doc2 =  Jsoup.connect(inHtml+bd.get(i).sigla+fimHtml).get();
            String atletas = doc2.select("a").text().toString();
            atletas = atletas.substring(1247, (atletas.length())-54).replace(" "+bd.get(i).sigla+" ","\n");
            escreve.println(i+"_ "+bd.get(i).pais +"\n "+atletas+"\n");

            System.out.println((i+"_ "+bd.get(i).pais +"\n "+atletas+"\n"));
            i++;
        }


        escreve.close();
        grava.close();
    }
}
```

A classe Nacoes tem apenas duas strings e seus getters/setters.

Segue um pedaço do codigo do site, caso alguém queira sugerir uma forma mais facil.

```
 {`  <div class="results container-narrow">
                                                                                                        <a href="/judoka/33416" class="judoka">
                            <div class="judoka__profile_image">
                                <img class="" src="https://78884ca60822a34fb0e6-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/profiles/200/33416.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="judoka__info">
                                <div class="family_name">ADRIANO</div>
                                <div class="given_name">Gabriel</div>
                                <div class="country">
                                    <img src="https://78884ca60822a34fb0e6-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/flags/20x15/bra.png" alt="">
                                    BRA
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                                                                                            <a href="/judoka/1039" class="judoka">
                            <div class="judoka__profile_image">
                                <img class="" src="https://78884ca60822a34fb0e6-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/profiles/200/1039.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="judoka__info">
                                <div class="family_name">AGUIAR</div>
                                <div class="given_name">Mayra</div>
                                <div class="country">
                                    <img src="https://78884ca60822a34fb0e6-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/flags/20x15/bra.png" alt="">
                                    BRA
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>`
}
```

Obrigado galera, abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi pesquisando o problema está nessa linha:

```
escreve.println(i+"_ "+bd.get(i).pais +"\n "+atletas+"\n");
```

Utilizando PrintWriter no Windows o correto é utilizar "\r\n" e print ao invés de println para pular linhas e não apenas "\n", então teria que ficar

```
escreve.print(i+"_ "+bd.get(i).pais +"\r\n"+atletas+"\r\n");
```

Uma outra forma de se fazer essa quebra de linha é utilizando `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: A opção do `getProperty` é melhor porque é agnóstica, ou seja, independe do sistema operacional.

Comment: Eu desconheço o getProperty, onde eu encaixaria ele? Adicionar o \r não funcionou.

Comment: dá pra  concatenar igual o \r\n...exemplo escreve.println(i+"_ "+bd.get(i).pais +System.getProperty("line.separator")+atletas+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Comment: Cara, obrigado pelo auxilio. Não funcionou, mas acho que talvez eu tenha que fazer uma raspagem mais especifica. Abraços.

Comment: como que a string atletas fica pra você? fica tipo jogador1\njogador2\njogador3 ?

Comment: A string na impressão fica um embaixo do outro, no txt, fica tudo na mesma linha, sem os \n. Ele pula de linha, quando muda o pais. Da forma que estou raspando, ele não pega atleta por atleta, ele pega pais por pais.

Comment: ah descobri, na verdade além de \r\n tem que substituir o println por apenas print tb, testa por gentileza testei aqui com umas coisas e deu certo

Comment: Haaaaa muleque, Funcionou cara. Po, muitissimo obrigado mano. Estava desanimando . Excelente.

Comment: beleza, joe, obrigado, alterei com a solução definita, marque como certa quando puder para ajudar a comunidade